# Sublime text 3 Anaconda goto definition not working with Django

Tags: django, plugins, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-anaconda

I'm using the plugin for Python development in Sublime Text 3 [Anaconda](https://github.com/DamnWidget/anaconda).

Everything works fine, but now that I have a django project, I want to also take advantage of Anaconda's features like `goto definition`.

Sadly, I can't get it to work. I tried adding paths to my project settings with no luck:

```
"settings": {
"python_interpreter": "C:/Users/user/virtualenvs/example/Scripts/python",
"extra_paths":
[
    "C:/Users/user/virtualenvs/example/Lib",
    "C:/Users/user/virtualenvs/example/Lib/site-packages/django"
]
}
```

Do you know how to overcome this problem?

Comment: Do you resolve this problem?

Comment: Once you select `goto definition` does it say `unable to find xxx` in the bottom panel?

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with this on MacOSX.

I had set the interpreter to be the one in the virtualenv for my Django project. I was thinking that is what they needed. Instead set it to the python interpreter that Sublime text is using. (In my case it was the system python)